# Access elements of List <List <List <List <Object> >>> titles = new ArrayList <List <List <List <Object> >>> ();

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following list `List <List <List <List <Object> >>> titles = new ArrayList <List <List <List <Object> >>> ();` and I would like to access the elements of it but I don't know how to do that ..

The list has 1 element that in its turn contains 3 elements and each of those 3 elements contains 6 elements but I don't know how to access each of them.

This is the output of the arraylist when I put it in a listview:

```
 1 element---> [[[12,"01",1,"Fallo de corriente",0,1],
 2 element---> [12,"01",2,"Nivel m\u00E1ximo (activaci\u00F3n)",0,0],
 3 element--->   [12,"01",3,"Nivel m\u00E1ximo(desactivaci\u00F3n)",0,1]]]
```

Within each element I have 6 elements as you can see, how can I access element 1 that has 6 elements inside and access each of them?

Comment: Instead of `List<List<List<List<Object>>>>`, maybe you should use classes instead?

Comment: `List<List<List<List<Object>>>>` isn't exaclty a great or understandable data structure. Have you considered creating actual custom classes that represent your data in a better way?

Comment: you can chain get(int index) calls, but imho you should think about a better way of storing your data

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS The problem I have is that it is the content of a rest service and the way is that unfortunately

Comment: @ItFreak The problem I have is that it is the content of a rest service and the way is that unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use that kind of structure, you can use something like this, e.g. to extract title of the first item.

```
String title1 = titles.get(0).get(0).get(0).get(3).toString();
```

So you have four levels of hierarchy, `titles` list is level 1 and `get(0)` will take the list it contains, `get(0)` will take first (and only item) of level 2, `get(0)` will take first out of 3 items of level 3, and finally `get(3)` will take fourth element of level 4 which is actual title as I can see.

So your `title1` should be `"Fallo de corriente"`

Comment: Actually so that it works for me as you put it, it looks like this:

String title1 = titles.get (0) .get (0) .get (0) .get (3) .toString ();

One more level ... For you to see how cumbersome the matter is ... Now the issue is to go through a for loop to access a certain element and put ifs and others

Answer (score 2):

You would probably have to revisit on how you are getting the data. By having ArrayList() inside another ArrayList() inside another ArrayList() ..... is a tiring work with loops iterating throughout the list.

And a nightmare for the programmer to find any error.

However, the general idea of solution would be

***Iterating through `List<Object>()`***

```
for(Object o: objectList){}
```

***Iterating through `List<List<Object>>`***

```
    for(List<Object> outerObjList: objectListList){
       for(Object innerObject: outerObjList){
       }
    }
```

And so on... It's complexity grows too much for any good developer to comprehend.

I'd not prefer to write loops for `List <List <List <List <Object> >>> titles` ever! And Ever! (Sort of a pun!).

If there is no other go (As you are getting it from some other source), I would do write a class to perform the mapping using Jackson ObjectMapper. Going forth, your code might be a little more readable as mentioned [here](https://makeinjava.com/convert-list-objects-to-from-json-java-jackson-objectmapper-example/)

<strike>Please read of how to Structure your Classes and possibility for reducing the level of nesting in loops.Maybe re-organize your data into 2-3 individual `Map`? Happy coding!</strike>

Comment: Annes A I know, I know it's very cumbersome but the data from the rest service gives me that, I asked them to change them but nothing, it's impossible ...

So I have to work with all this mess ...

Comment: You can write custom Classes to Map it with your `Object`(s). However, your mappings will fail if the response changes the field names. Have mentioned how in the answer.

Comment: Annes A The problem is that the normal thing is that the names change and so on ... Which makes me a mess ... But this is what I have to work with ...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if the storing in lists of lists is superfluous and you are only interested in the values of the inner list. If so, does flatmapping help you for further processing?

```
List <Object> result = titles.stream()
                            .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
                            .flatMap(y -> y.stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
//[[12, 01, 1, Fallo de corriente, 0, 1], [12, 01, 2, Nivel máximo (activación), 0, 0], [12, 01, 3, Nivel máximo(desactivación), 0, 1]]
```

Or add one more step to get a list of each value:

```
List <Object> result = titles.stream()
                            .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
                            .flatMap(y -> y.stream())
                            .flatMap(z -> z.stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);

//[12, 01, 1, Fallo de corriente, 0, 1, 12, 01, 2, Nivel máximo (activación), 0, 0, 12, 01, 3, Nivel máximo(desactivación), 0, 1]
```